# SSIS Data Flow Tab missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

This is bugging me from two days too as "SSIS Data Flow Items" and "SSIS Control Flow Items" tabs from "Choose Toolbox Items"(Tools menu option) are missing. I have followed the below procedure and please note my development environment VM details.

### Development Environment VM Details

1. Operating System: Windows Server 2012 SP1
2. SQL Version 2012: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3153.0 (X64)
3. SharePoint 2013: SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License
4. Visual Studio 2012: Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938
5. SQL Server Data Tools Version: 11.1.20627.00

### Procedure

1. I installed Integration Services on my SQL Instance and also installed the SQL Server 2012 Data Tools.
2. I deployed the SharePointListAdapters.msi from the Codeplex. I restarted the VM as well.
3. I created 4 "Visual Studio 2012 Integration Services Project(s) in Framework(s) 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5.

In all the above projects, I am NOT able to see the "SSIS Data Flow Items" and "SSIS Control Flow Items" tabs from "Choose Toolbox Items"(Tools menu option).
Also, in order to follow steps as mentioned in this post, I see that "ChangeCase.dll" is missing from the path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents"

What am I missing?

Comment: You mention installing SQL Server 2012 Data Tools; did you also install [SQL Server 2012 Data Tools - Business Intelligence](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)?

Answer (score 3):

Open up a package and click on the canvas.

Either under "SSIS" at the top or by right-clicking the canvas there should be an item "SSIS Toolbox" which will bring up what you're looking for.